# Given a matrix, how can you tell if it is an exponential matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Of course if you can find a matrix $B$ such that $A=\exp(B)$ then you know that $A$ is an exponential matrix. But finding such $B$ is not always trivial.

Are there criteria to know if a matrix is an exponential matrix (or, equivalently I guess, that it defines a matrix-$\log$)?

I'm asking this because a somebody once saw a matrix and said "oh, that's an exponential matrix". I didn't find any other solution than computing its logarithm with Mathematica and conclude he was right!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we allow complex matrices, then every non-singular matrix is an exponential matrix.  See, for example, the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750978/using-the-jordan-form-complex).

Comment: Every **non-singular** matrix ; my mistake